# Why do these HTML elements within .NET Razor have extra spacing caused by new lines?

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following HTML to render a date input box with an icon:

```
@if (Model.ShowThis){
    <input id="box1" type="hidden" value="@Model.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" size="10" />
    <span id="icon1" class="picture"></span>
}
```

[image: Icon shifted to the right]

You'll notice that the icon is shifted to the right. If I modify the code to be:

```
@if (Model.ShowThis){
    <input id="box1" type="hidden" value="@Model.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" size="10" /><!--
    --><span id="icon1" class="picture"></span>
}
```

[image: Icon in correct place]

you will notice that there is no longer a shift due to the removal of any potential white space. Without these comments, I can go into the debugger and see extra spacing between the elements, which once removed, fixes the problem as well.

Why are standard new lines within a .cshtml file (inside a Razor block) causing there to be non-breaking spaces between these HTML elements? I have never seen this behavior before in other files in the same type of scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're seeing white-space in your HTML document rendered as these are both `inline-block` elements, I'm guessing.

Think of them not as elements on a page, then, but words in a sentence.  The browser does it this way.  So, if I put:

```
<div>
  Here
  is
  a
  sentence.
</div>
```

in HTML, I'd expect to see:

> Here is a sentence.

in my document. This is because HTML interprets aggregate strings of white-space (including line breaks and register returns) as cumulatively one space when rendering.  It expects a tag to forcibly break a line, if that's the desire.  Given `white-space: normal` (the CSS default), if there's not enough space for the text on the line, then it will wrap.  This allows for well-formatted and readable HTML (which is an aside, but it's important to understand *why* it works this way).

It's the same story with `inline` or `inline-block` elements.  They're handled much like text in layout, and thus respect surrounding white-space.  **That's good, because that's intended behavior for inline elements.**  You just need to make some special considerations when you lay out your document using those display properties.

Either leave your HTML comment in the code, or use this pattern in CSS:

```
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
.container > * {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

where `.container` is whatever wrapper you have around the offending elements.

Comment: Can you explain the CSS solution you offered? I tried this and it ended up shifting the icon down, instead of back to the left as it should be. What is the idea behind using font-size to accomplish this?

Comment: `font-size` will determine the white-space rendered in the container.  When it's `0`, that white-space won't render, just like a character wouldn't render with a `font-size: 0` rule.  It's probably the reset that's the culprit.  Try to determine the original font-size, and instead of `1rem` (which is basically resetting it to document root `font-size`), set it to whatever it was before the `font-size: 0` was applied to the container.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Razor thing; even static HTML would have the same problem. Whitespace will unfortunately affect layout, whether it's line breaks or spaces.